# Find the complex Fourier transform of $f(x) = \dfrac{1}{1 + x^2 + x^4}$.

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, residue-calculus

How do I find the complex Fourier transform of $f(x) = \dfrac{1}{1 + x^2 + x^4}$?

I know that the complex Fourier transform is $\hat{f}(k) = \displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)e^{-ikx}\ dx$.

Another trick I thought of doing is writing $x^2 + x^4 + 1$ as $(x^2 - x + 1)(x^2 + x + 1)$ where the roots of $x^2 - x + 1$ are $x = \dfrac{1 \pm \sqrt{3}i}{2}$ and the roots of $x^2 + x + 1$ are $x = \dfrac{-1 \pm \sqrt{3}i}{2}$. But then how do I calculate the Residue to find the complex Fourier transform.

Also, I need to  use direct integration to find the inverse Fourier transform of the $\hat{f}(k)$ that I find and check that I recover $f(x) = \dfrac{1}{1 + x^2 + x^4}$

Comment: Going off the factorization of the denominator, have you tried using partial fraction decomposition and completing the square with the denominators?

Comment: Finding the residue should be very easy by partial fraction decomposition... I expect a proble to arise with $\exp$ when you want to use the residue theorem. A little trick is needed there.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Fourier+transform+calculator&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22FourierTransformCalculator%22%2C+%22transformfunction%22%7D+-%3E%221%2F%28t%5E4%2Bt%5E2%2B1%29%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22FourierTransformCalculator%22%2C+%22variable1%22%7D+-%3E%22t%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22FourierTransformCalculator%22%2C+%22variable2%22%7D+-%3E%22w%22

Comment: How do you actually find the residue of that?

Answer (score 1):

Let me show you what I think is the easiest way to compute the residues. You've already shown that

$$ f(z) = \frac{1}{(z - \alpha_1)(z - \alpha_2)(z - \alpha_3)(z - \alpha_4)},$$

where $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3, \alpha_4$ are the four roots that you computed in your original question.

So how do we determine the residue at $z = \alpha_1$ (say)?

Let's consider the function

$$ g(z) = \frac{1}{(z - \alpha_2)(z - \alpha_3)(z - \alpha_4)},$$
defined on $\mathbb C \setminus \{ \alpha_2, \alpha_3, \alpha_4 \}$.

If $B_\delta(\alpha_1)$ is an open disk around $\alpha_1$, small enough that it doesn't contain $\alpha_2, \alpha_3, \alpha_4$, then $g$ is holomorphic on $B_\delta(\alpha_1)$. So $g$ can be represented by a Taylor series on $B_\delta(\alpha_1)$:
$$ g(z) = g(\alpha_1) + g'(\alpha_1) (z - \alpha_1) + \frac 1 {2!} g''(\alpha_1) (z - \alpha_1)^2 + \dots$$

On the *punctured* open disk $B_\delta ' (\alpha_1) = B_\delta (\alpha_1) \setminus \{ \alpha_1 \}$, we have $g(z) = (z - \alpha_1) f(z)$. Thus, on this punctured disk, we have
$$ f(z) = \frac{g(\alpha_1)}{z - \alpha_1} + g'(\alpha_1) + \frac 1 {2!} g''(\alpha_1) (z - \alpha_1) + \dots$$
This is the Laurent series for $f(z)$! So the coefficient of the $(z - \alpha_1)^{-1}$ term in this series the residue of $f$ at $\alpha_1$. Thus
$$ \text{Res}_{z = \alpha_1}  = g(\alpha_1). $$

It remains to evaluate $g(\alpha_1)$. That's easy - it's
$$ g(\alpha_1) = \frac{1} {(\alpha_1 - \alpha_2)(\alpha_1 - \alpha_3)(\alpha_1 - \alpha_4)}$$

---

Taking a step back, it's worth noting that this method can be used to compute the residue of any meromorphic function at a simple pole. If $f(z)$ has a simple pole at $\alpha$, then $g(z) = (z - \alpha)f(z)$ has a removable singularity at $\alpha$ and $\lim_{z \to \alpha} g(z)$ is the constant term in the Taylor series for $g$ at $\alpha$, which is also the coefficient of the $(z - \alpha)^{-1}$ term in the Laurent series for $f$ at $\alpha$ (i.e. the residue of $f$ at $\alpha$).