# Difference between $\int$ and $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}$

Tags: integration

I was browsing questions and I found [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4660238/1022719) which uses a definite integral from negative infinity to positive infinity. I then wondered if there was a difference between that and the indefinite integral. Common sense would say they are exactly the same, but I don't trust my common sense. Here are the two integrals for reference: $$\int$$ $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}$$
This is not a duplicate as that question asks for the difference between definite and indefinite integrals in general but this one asks whether these two integrals are the same.

Comment: The indefinite integral, when it exists, is a function defined up to an additive constant.  The definite integral, when it exists, is a number.

Comment: They are not the same, but some texts use the former as a shorthand for the latter.

Comment: One ($\int$) is a (class of) function(s), the other ($\int_{-\infty}^\infty$) is a number (typically interpreted as an area).

Comment: Regarding your edit:  this *is* a duplicate, with $a = -b = \infty$.  The two notations mean different things, exactly as described in the answers to that question (as has been pointed out in the comments here).